# PHP-FPM Xdebug causes SIGSEGV

Tags: php, nginx, xdebug

Enabling Xdebug on nginx server with php-fpm causes SIGSEGV error logged in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2015/07/26 20:30:37 [error] 28452#28452: *326 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.50.1, server: mydomain.dev, request: "POST /admin/soap/add/95 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "mydomain.dev", referrer: "http://mydomain.dev/admin/soap/add/95"
```

When I disable Xdebug errors are gone.

Script which is causing this error sends SOAP request to the external service.

In my opinion this might be some kind of buggy configuration e.g. exceeding max connection number or something like this, but I have no idea how to find it.

The server which I'm working on is Vagrant box https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV.